# Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift3, crashlytics

This is my first post on Stackoverflow so please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

I have a Swift iOS app and I got the following crash from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x184f0afe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18396c538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184dec898 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding
3  Reserv                         0x1003500c0 -[ICMDataManager updateInboxWithConversation:]
4  Reserv                         0x10037a714 __83-[ICMNativeConversationContentViewController replyToConversationWithBlocks:upload:]_block_invoke
5  Reserv                         0x100358958 __69+[ICMHTTPBridge replyToConversation:withBlocks:upload:success:error:]_block_invoke_2
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x183dc29e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x183dc29a0 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x183dc75e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
9  CoreFoundation                 0x184eb90c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x184eb6ce4 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x184de6da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x186851074 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKit                          0x18b0a1c9c UIApplicationMain
14 Reserv                         0x1000824d4 main (UserPlacesModule.swift:23)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x183df559c start
```

However UserPlacesModule.swift:23 is the following line:

```
21 protocol UserPlacesModuleProtocol {
22     
23 }
24 
25class UserPlacesModule : ModuleProtocol{
```

Which does not help at all. So is there any suggestion on what can cause this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the protocol needs to conform to the `class`. In line 21, try `protocol UserPlacesModuleProtocol: class`. Xcode normally gives a warning about this though...

Comment: Show the definition for `updateInboxWithConversation` method

Comment: Your log points to `(UserPlacesModule.swift:23)` as `main` right after `start`. That is the application entry point I believe (like the `main()` function in C and C++). Accordingly, the bottom of the stack is the place farthest away from the crash.

Comment: Typically, You want to look at the highest line that represents code you have the source for (i.e., your own code, **not** system libraries, third party frameworks, etc.).

Comment: @mag_zbc Oh that is a method within a library, Intercom. So I guess the issue is in the library then. Thanks for the comment.